# How to get distance between mouse point to a specific object in Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

What I want to archive is, get distance between mouse pointer when user clicks, to a pre define image.

Let's say there is an image in [0,0]position, and when user clicks on the screen [9,10], I need to get distance between those 2 positions in m or cm.

Is there any way of doing this in phaser 3? Your help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(imageSprite.y - MousePointer.y,2)+Math.pow(imageSprite.x - MousePointer.x,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Phaser has utility methods built into a couple of namespaces. The one you can here is `Phaser.Math.Distance`. You are right with world x/y values, which aren't translated by moving the camera.

```
import * as Phaser from "phaser";

new Phaser.Game({
  scene: {
    create
  }
});

function create(this: Phaser.Scene) {
  const rect = this.add.rectangle(200, 200, 30, 30, 0xff0000);
  this.input.on(Phaser.Input.Events.POINTER_DOWN, (pointer: Phaser.Input.Pointer) => {
    const dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY, rect.x, rect.y);
    console.log(dist);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can get the mouse cordinates like this. I used this code insde the mouse click

```
 var pointer = this.input.activePointer;

      console.log([
        'x: ' + pointer.worldX,
        'y: ' + pointer.worldY,
        'isDown: ' + pointer.isDown,
        'rightButtonDown: ' + pointer.rightButtonDown()
      ]);
```

And we can get the an image position like this

```
 this.x1 = this.elephantImage.x.toFixed();
 this.y1 = this.elephantImage.y.toFixed();
```

We can get the distance like this

```
 var dx = this.x1 - this.x2;
 var dy = this.y1 - this.y2;
 var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
 console.log("distance--->" + distance.toFixed());
```